# Recording a video filtered with CIFilter is too slow

Tags: ios, swift, video, avassetwriter, cifilter

I am trying to crop and upscale a video while recording it.
I use `AssetWriter` to save video and `CIFilters` for live filtering.

The problem is that recording is really slow.

Details (first 6 steps are just boilerplate code, so feel free to skip them):

1. Set devices, e.g. back camera and mic;
2. Set up `CIContext` for GPU usage as it described [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-SW5):

   ```
   func setupContext() {
       // setup the GLKView for video/image preview
       OGLContext = EAGLContext(api: EAGLRenderingAPI.openGLES2)

       ciContext = CIContext.init(eaglContext: OGLContext!)
   }
   ```
3. Setting up `GLKView`;

   ```
   func setUpGLPreview(){
       glView.context = OGLContext!
       glView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = false
       glView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
       glView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 20.0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.width * 9/16)
       glView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  view.bounds.width * 9/16, height: view.bounds.width)
       glView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
       glView.bindDrawable()
       previewBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: glView.drawableWidth, height: glView.drawableHeight)
   }
   ```
4. Configuring `AVCaptureSession`;
5. Configuring inputs for `AssetWriter`:

   ```
   func configureVideoSessionWithAsset(){
       let compressionSettings: [String: Any] = [
           AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: NSNumber(value: 20000000),
           AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: NSNumber(value: 1),
           AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline41
       ]


       let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
           AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
           AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionSettings,
           AVVideoWidthKey  : 1080,
           AVVideoHeightKey : 1920,
           AVVideoScalingModeKey:AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill
       ]

       assetWriterInputCamera = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
       let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary : [String: Any] = [
           String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
           String(kCVPixelBufferWidthKey) : 1080,
           String(kCVPixelBufferHeightKey) : 1920,
           String(kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility) : kCFBooleanTrue
       ]

       bufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterInputCamera!, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

       assetWriterInputCamera?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

       let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
       assetWriterInputCamera?.transform = transform

       let audioSettings : [String : Any] = [
           AVFormatIDKey : NSInteger(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
           AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
           AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: 44100.0)
       ]

       assetWriterInputAudio = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
       assetWriterInputAudio?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
       }
   ```
6. Creating new Writer each time we start capturing:

   ```
   func createNewWriter(){
       let outputPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + Date().description + "output" + "\(state.currentFileFormat.rawValue)"
       let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
       let fileType = (state.currentFileFormat == .mov) ? AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie : AVFileTypeMPEG4
       self.assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputFileURL, fileType: fileType)

       if let videoInput = assetWriterInputCamera{
           self.assetWriter?.add(videoInput)
       }

       if let audioInput = assetWriterInputAudio{
           self.assetWriter?.add(audioInput)
       }
   }
   ```
7. Finally, recording and filtering:

   ```
   var cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
   var scaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")

   func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

       sessionQueue.async {
           guard let imgBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer), let previewBounds = self.previewBounds else{
       return
           }
           //recording audio
           if self.state.isRecording{
               if let audio = self.assetWriterInputAudio, connection.audioChannels.count > 0 && audio.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                   self.writerQueue.async {
                       audio.append(sampleBuffer)
                   }
                   return
               }
           }

           let sourceImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imgBuffer)

           //setting drawRect
           let sourceAspect = sourceImage.extent.size.width / sourceImage.extent.size.height;
           let previewAspect = previewBounds.size.width  / previewBounds.size.height;

           var drawRect = sourceImage.extent
           if (sourceAspect > previewAspect){
               drawRect.size.width = drawRect.size.height * previewAspect
           } else{
               drawRect.size.height = drawRect.size.width / previewAspect
           }

           //Not recording just showing the preview
           if(self.assetWriter == nil || self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.completed){
               self.glView.bindDrawable()
               if(self.OGLContext != EAGLContext.current()){
                   EAGLContext.setCurrent(self.OGLContext)
               }

               glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0)
               glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
               glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
               glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_ONE), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA))

               self.ciContext?.draw(sourceImage, in: previewBounds, from: drawRect)
               self.glView.display()
           } else{
               if !self.state.isRecording {
                   return
               }

               let outputResolution = (self.state.currentCamera == .back) ? CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 604, height: 1080) : CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 405, height: 720)
               cropFilter?.setValue(sourceImage,
                           forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

               cropFilter?.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputResolution.width, height:  outputResolution.height)), 
                           forKey: "inputRectangle")

               var filteredImage:CIImage? = sourceImage.cropping(to: outputResolution)

               scaleFilter?.setValue(filteredImage, 
                            forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
               scaleFilter?.setValue(1080/filteredImage!.extent.width, 
                            forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

               filteredImage = scaleFilter?.outputImage

               //Checking if we started writing
               if self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown{
                   if  self.assetWriter?.startWriting != nil {
                       self.assetWriter?.startWriting()
                       self.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime:  CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))
                  }
              }

              let time = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
              var newPixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer? = nil
              guard let bufferPool = self.bufferAdaptor?.pixelBufferPool else{
               return
              }

              if let filteredImage = filteredImage{
                  CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, bufferPool, &newPixelBuffer)
                  self.ciContext?.render(filteredImage, to: newPixelBuffer!, bounds: filteredImage.extent, colorSpace: nil)

                   self.glView.bindDrawable()
                   glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0)
                   glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
                   glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
                   glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_ONE), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA))
                   self.ciContext?.draw(filteredImage, in: previewBounds, from: filteredImage.extent)
                   self.glView.display()
              }

              if let camera = self.assetWriterInputCamera ,camera.isReadyForMoreMediaData{
                  self.writerQueue.async {
                      self.bufferAdaptor?.append(newPixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: time)
                  }
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Preview works fine before capturing starts. During capturing frame rate drops dramatically to unusable level.

The question is: what am I doing wrong in the last step? 
`CIImage` filtering supposed to be very fast due to GPU usage, but instead everything is frozen.

Please note:

- I know about `GPUImage`, but I think it's an overkill for this task;
- I've checked out Apple's `CIFunHouse` and RosyWriter projects. The first helped me a lot to set everything up. The second uses shaders to filter video which is a bit complicated for me.

Any help and comments appreciated!
If you have any questions about the code, please ask!

Thanks!

Comment: One CoreImage resource I always suggest is Simon Gladman (http://www.flexmonkey.com). He has several repos available, but one that may help you out is https://github.com/FlexMonkey/LiveCameraFiltering. It's probably written in Swift 2, but most of his repos have a blog attached explaining things and I've found most of his Swift 2 -> Swift 3 conversions pretty straightforwards.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion, will try it!

I checked his blog before, during the research and found this post very helpful:
http://flexmonkey.blogspot.ru/2016/04/loading-filtering-saving-videos-in-swift.html

It's not about live recording though.

Comment: Here's two that are: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/applying-cifilters-to-live-camera-feed.html http://flexmonkey.blogspot.ru/2015/12/cartooneyes-compositing-cartoon-eyes.html Hope they help!

Comment: @VladimirAgeev did you solve the slow recording issue ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Any update on this?